# How does the screen backlight work?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, display, brightness

Everything about the backlight settings and controls work for me except:

Backlight resets to max. on every reboot/boot.
The backlight minimum goes on to complete black screen, instead of the minimum brightness setting elsewhere.
NB> I see that 1. above is answered on a lot of places with different answers, so I am actually looking for someone or somplace where I can read and understand how it all works.

I have 2 different backlight folders in my laptop and many conf files to edit. So need to understand what on those files impacts what on the sytem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the heart of backlighting is this Linux Kernel parameter that's exposed to you through here under `/sys`. You can manipulate it by setting the value to something between 1 and 15. For example:

```
$ echo 5 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

Set's the brightness to 5. Manipulating this Kernel parameter is abstracted away so that when you're changing the value with your keyboard or a desktop applet you're manipulating it through [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus/) and [HAL](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/hal/).

D-Bus is allowing you to manipulate this structure, `org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.KeyboardBacklight`, and [HAL](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/hal/) is allowing the privilege to do so. You can see this on my Fedora 14 system like this:

```
$ grep -i backlight /etc/dbus-1/system.d/*
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/hal.conf:         send_interface="org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.KeyboardBacklight"/>
/etc/dbus-1/system.d/hal.conf:         send_interface="org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.KeyboardBacklight"/>
```

In the file `hal.conf`:

```
  <!-- Only allow users at the local console to manipulate devices -->
  <policy at_console="true">
  ...
      <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.Hal"
           send_interface="org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.KeyboardBacklight"/>
```

You can query the current value, through D-Bus like so:

```
$ dbus-send \
     --print-reply \
     --system \
     --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal  \
     /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer_backlight \
     org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.LaptopPanel.GetBrightness | \
     tail -1 | \
     awk '{print $2}'
```

Which returns the value:

```
15
```

You can also manipulate it from the command line like so, (the bit `int32:10` below is setting brightness to "10"):

```
$ dbus-send \
     --print-reply \
     --system \
     --dest=org.freedesktop.Hal  \
     /org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer_backlight \
     org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.LaptopPanel.SetBrightness \
     int32:10 #2&>1 > /dev/null
```

You can see that we changed the brightness:

```
$ cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
10
```

#### So how do I fix this?

One idea would be to save the current brightness out to a file prior to either a shutdown and/or reboot and then add to your startup (perhaps `~/.xinitrc`) the `dbus-send ...` command above adding in the brightness value you previously saved out to the file.

#### Why do I have multiple files under /sys/class/backlight?

I came across this Q&A on askubuntu.com titled: [Why there are two brightness control file (/sys/class/) in my system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134984/why-there-are-two-brightness-control-file-sys-class-in-my-system). In the answer to this there was this comment:

> If the system starts with the kernel parameter acpi_backlight=vendor,
>   the item acpi_video0 is replaced by the item intel, but then the
>   Fn-Keys can not change the value of this item.

I also came across this documentation for the Kernel, titled: [Kernel Parameters](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt). In this doc the following aCPI options are mentioned:

```
acpi_backlight= [HW,ACPI]
        acpi_backlight=vendor
        acpi_backlight=video
        If set to vendor, prefer vendor specific driver
        (e.g. thinkpad_acpi, sony_acpi, etc.) instead
        of the ACPI video.ko driver.
```

I think the `intel_backlight` referenced in `/sys/class/backlight` is part of the backlighting for the video card drivers provided for Intel graphics cards.

#### References

- [Save brightness setting on reboot in Debian Squeeze / Wheezy](http://synapse.wordpress.com/2012/05/22/save-brightness-setting-on-reboot-in-debian-squeeze-wheezy/)
- [DBUS Backlight Brightness](http://wiki.ninjafocus.net/DBUS_Backlight_Brightness)

Comment: Thank you. I do understand the part for acpi backlight...that's the kind of info I am looking for. But any idea why I also have another folder `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight`

Comment: @charlie - some additional info, not sure if it's what you wnat, lmk.

Comment: Please take note that [HAL](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/hal/) has been deprecated. Now `xrandr --set backlight` or `xbacklight` is the official "abstracted" way (provided your gpu driver supports it)

Comment: This `sudo echo 5 > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` will not work, you need to use `echo 5 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`

Comment: @DaniëlW.Crompton - ty I'll fix that, nice catch